# How can I migrate from single-partition Ubuntu to dual-booting Ubuntu/Windows 8?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, encryption

I am currently running 12.04 on a single partition, no encryption. I have some Windows-only software [*] that I need to run, so I want to migrate to a 13.10 (with full disk encryption) / Windows 8 dual boot. How can I do this?

Notes:

- I have my original Windows discs.
- I have backed up my data, so I don't mind starting from a blank slate (i.e. I can avoid a 12.04 > 12.10 > 13.04 > 13.10 upgrade path).

[*] I've tried both Wine and VirtualBox, but neither is performant. I'm obviously appealing the developer for an Ubuntu version, but I need a short-term solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps :(includes formatting the entire disk and will get a fresh system)

**Step 1:**

> Boot from windows 8 disk and modify the partitions as you wish. Keep in mind that you will need partitions for
>   1. Windows
>   2. Ubuntu
>   3. Swap space
>   4. Other Data
>   So, install windows in the partition you prefer.

**Step 2:**

> Insert the Ubuntu disk and install Ubuntu in the partition you prefer by allocating some Swap space.

That's it. Normally both the OS will dual boot without any problem. But if you are not getting any GRUB (Boot menu) , You should run the Boot repair. Use the following link as a reference for Boot repair : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 1):

I'll give it to you in 3 easy steps:

- Partition hard drive from a liveCD using gparted.
- Install Windows 8.
- Fix MBR with a grub rescue disk.

And your done!

Read up my young one:

How to resize LUKS: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=726724

How to use GParted: http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html#mozTocId661277

How to fix MBR: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: do you explaining how to partition the hdd? I'm guessing the windows partition should be physically first, formatted to NTFS, flagged as boot? and are you saying that I won't need to reinstall ubuntu - the current installation is preserved somehow when repartitioning?

Comment: Read up my young one: 
How to resize LUKS: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=726724
How to use GParted: http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html#mozTocId661277
How to fix MBR: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows